# Visualize a string/sequence, emphasizing certain substrings

Tags: list-manipulation, visualization, segmentation

I need to visualize a sequence, with the ability to emphasize certain segments.

For example, take this sequence `seq`:

```
seq = "-----------------DTLCIGYHANNSTDTVDTVLEKNVTVTHSVNLLEDKHNGKLCK
LRGVAPLHLGKCNIAGWILGNPECESLSTASSWSYIVETPSSDNGTCYPGDFIDYEELREQLSSVSSFER
FEIFPKTSSWPNHDSNKGVTAACPHAGAKSFYKNLIWLVKKGNSYPKLSKSYINDKGKEVLVLWGIHHPS
TSADQQSLYQNADTYVFVGSSRYSKKFKPEIAIRPKVRDQEGRMNYYWTLVEPGDKITFEATGNLVVPRY
AFAMERNAGSGIIISDTPVHDCNTTCQTPKGAINTSLPFQNIHPITIGKCPKYVKSTKLRLATGLRNIPS
G----LFGAIAGFIEGGWTGMVDGWYGYHHQNEQGSGYAADLKSTQNAIDEITNKVNSVIEKMNTQFTAV
GKEFNHLEKRIENLNKKVDDGFLDIWTYNAELLVLLENERTLDYHDSNVKNLYEKVRSQLKNNAKEIGNG
CFEFYHKCDNTCMESVKNGTYDYPKYSEEAKLNREEIDS-------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

The list of segments I want to emphasize:

```
segments = {"AGSGIIISDTPVHDC", "AIDEITNKVNSVIEK", "AKSFYKNLIWLVKKG"}
```

I'm thinking that something that looks like this would work for the emphasis, where the black line is the length of the sequence, and the blue boxes are the segments:

[image]

To get start and ending positions of each segment, we can use `StringPosition[seq, #] & /@ segments`.

Now I'm not sure which visualization tool would help me visualize this sequence and emphasize the segment using these start and end positions.

Comment: how about `StringReplace[seq, 
 s : Alternatives @@ segments :> 
  ToString[Style[s, Red, Bold], StandardForm]]`?

Comment: That's definitely good, and I actually already had something similar to that, but I need something that's more pictorial, thanks though! @kglr

Comment: I just noticed that this non-pictorial expression would not work with overlapping segments, but your answer below does. @kglr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Gray, EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[LightBlue], 
   SequenceReplace[Flatten[Join[{1}, {#[[1]] - 1, 
     Rectangle[{#[[1]], -5}, {#[[2]], 5}], #[[2]] + 1} & /@ 
   StringPosition[seq, Alternatives @@ segments], {StringLength @ seq}]],
 {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> Line[{{a, 0}, {b, 0}}]]}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Also

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[LightBlue], 
  Rectangle[{#[[1]], -5}, {#[[2]], 5}]& /@ StringPosition[seq, Alternatives @@ segments]},
  Axes -> {True, False}, Ticks -> None, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, StringLength @ seq}, Automatic}, ImageSize -> 800, 
  Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `NumberLinePlot`:

```
NumberLinePlot[Interval/@StringPosition[seq,  Alternatives @@ segments], 
 Spacings -> 0, Ticks -> None, ImageSize -> 600, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], PointSize[0], CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.02]], 
 PlotRange->{{0, StringLength @ seq}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Just had to adjust image size. This answer is amazing because it works for the rest of my segments, as well, which overlap... And it works.

Answer (score 6):

seq must be a string

```
Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{0, 15}, {StringLength@seq, 15}}], 
Rectangle[{#, 0}, {#2, 30}] & @@@ StringPosition[seq, segments]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Interval` functionality:**

```
seq = "-----------------DTLCIGYHANNSTDTVDTVLEKNVTVTHSVNLLEDKHNGKLCK
LRGVAPLHLGKCNIAGWILGNPECESLSTASSWSYIVETPSSDNGTCYPGDFIDYEELREQLSSVSSFER
FEIFPKTSSWPNHDSNKGVTAACPHAGAKSFYKNLIWLVKKGNSYPKLSKSYINDKGKEVLVLWGIHHPS
TSADQQSLYQNADTYVFVGSSRYSKKFKPEIAIRPKVRDQEGRMNYYWTLVEPGDKITFEATGNLVVPRY
AFAMERNAGSGIIISDTPVHDCNTTCQTPKGAINTSLPFQNIHPITIGKCPKYVKSTKLRLATGLRNIPS
G----LFGAIAGFIEGGWTGMVDGWYGYHHQNEQGSGYAADLKSTQNAIDEITNKVNSVIEKMNTQFTAV
GKEFNHLEKRIENLNKKVDDGFLDIWTYNAELLVLLENERTLDYHDSNVKNLYEKVRSQLKNNAKEIGNG
CFEFYHKCDNTCMESVKNGTYDYPKYSEEAKLNREEIDS-------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------";

segments = {"AGSGIIISDTPVHDC", "AIDEITNKVNSVIEK", "AKSFYKNLIWLVKKG"};

pos = StringPosition[seq, segments];
iv = Interval @@ pos
arr = Array[Boole@IntervalMemberQ[iv, #] &, {StringLength@seq}];
width = 30;

ArrayPlot[ConstantArray[arr, width], 
 ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 0 -> Yellow}, Frame -> False, 
 Mesh -> {Range[width/2, width/2], None}, MeshStyle -> Black, 
 Axes -> {True, False}]]
```

[image]